# Is there an omniauth strategy for Google login using openid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, omniauth

I know there's a `google-apps` strategy which uses openid.  And I know it's possible to configure Omniauth's generic openid strategy to work with regular (non-apps) google accounts.

I also know there's a google oauth strategy.  But for basic authentication, there's no need to register an app with Google because openid lets you authenticate without any such prerequisites.  (And Google's form to register an app is 500ing on me right now.)

So what I'm looking for is an omniauth strategy that does google openid login for non-apps accounts.  Should be extremely simple, and I might just build it.  But I thought I'd ask here if anybody knew of one first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a custom strategy for this. If you want to be able to have a one-click Google sign in button there are two options:

First you can just link to it by pre-supplying the OpenID identifier. Set up a normal OmniAuth OpenID strategy and then add something like this to your views:

```
<a href='/auth/open_id?openid_url=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'>Sign in with Google</a>
```

Alternatively you can configure an OpenID strategy specific to Google using OmniAuth::OpenID. This is actually an example from the README:

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :open_id, :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

In this case just send users to `/auth/google`.

Comment: That is very simple.  I still think there's value in a gem that does this one line of config for you, because it's a common enough case that it shouldn't even require understanding that openid is the right technology to use.  But for now I'll fall into the same trap that's prevented anybody else from building this gem.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use devise and omniauth. Check out the [devise OmniAuth Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) it shows how to setup openID for google and yahoo with omniauth.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on how to configure the openid strategy for google.  I'm looking for something fairly specific though, which is an omniauth strategy as a gem which does this automatically.